# javascript - make a screenshot button for video with background together

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am new with js and html,
i have a background picture with character that his head removed.
instead of the head there is a webcam open for someone to put
his head instead of the character.
its work fine but i want to add a **button** that will
give me option to capture webcam + the background together (picture with head's of someone in webcam + character background) and save it to my local computer. html2canvas not working for me cause its not working with flash.
when i tried my code its saving me only a capture of the webcam without the background together. 
will be great if someone will help me with that, again, thanks a lot! 
this is my code until now:

```js
<script>
const vid = document.querySelector('video');
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}) // request cam
.then(stream => {
  vid.srcObject = stream; // don't use createObjectURL(MediaStream)
  return vid.play(); // returns a Promise
})
.then(()=>{ // enable the button
  const btn = document.querySelector('button');
  btn.disabled = false;
  btn.onclick = e => {
    takeASnap()
    .then(download);
  };
})
.catch(e=>console.log('please use the fiddle instead'));

function takeASnap(){
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas'); // create a canvas
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); // get its context
  canvas.width = vid.videoWidth; // set its size to the one of the video
  canvas.height = vid.videoHeight;
  ctx.drawImage(vid, 0,0); // the video
  return new Promise((res, rej)=>{
    canvas.toBlob(res, 'image/jpeg'); // request a Blob from the canvas
  });
}
function download(blob){
  // uses the <a download> to download a Blob
  let a = document.createElement('a'); 
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.download = 'screenshot.jpg';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
}</script>
```

```css
<style>

#tv_container {
    width: 1920px; /* Adjust picture image width */
    height: 1080px; /* Adjust picture image height */
    position: relative;
}
#tv_container:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: url('images/edison.png') no-repeat top left transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
#tv_container video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px; /* Adjust top position */
    left: 600px; /* Adjust left position */
    z-index: 5;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="stuff, to, help, search, engines, not" name="keywords">
<meta content="What this page is about." name="description">
<meta content="Display Webcam Stream" name="title">
<title>newton</title>
  
</head>
  
<body>
<div id="tv_container">
<video id="vid"></video>
</div>
<button>take a snapshot</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will likely need to composite those two things (webcam screenshot and background image) yourself. You'd get the screenshot from the camera then use canvas drawing APIs to put it in a new canvas that also has the background.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you help me with the code?